# function array and strange behaviour

Tags: javascript

I have the following code:

```
var arr = [{Name: "foo", action: function(){ alert("foo")}},
       {Name: "bar", action: function(){ alert("bar")}}
      ]

var arr2 = {};

for(var i =0; i< arr.length; i++)
{
    var bla = arr[i];
    arr2[bla.Name] = function(){ bla.action() };
}          

arr2.foo();
arr2.bar();
```

that alerts two times "bar".
when instead I do

```
    arr2[bla.Name] = bla.action;
```

that works.

any way to make it works in the first case (I need to append other things in my function)

Thanks !

Comment: Just note that `arr2 = {}` actually makes `arr2` an object.

Comment: @AlvinWong: He *should* be using an object here. He has string keys.

Comment: Closure. Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work

Comment: @Mark - Yes, so it should have a name that doesn't imply it's an array...

Comment: @nnnnnn: Alvin originally said he should use `[]`. If you want to talk about naming, he should be choosing more descriptive names altogether, not solely based on type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because your `bla` inside your anonymous function is a reference and it keeps being updated inside the loop to point to the next object. When the loop terminates they will all point to the last element you referenced inside your loop.

You can fix it by doing something like

```
arr2[bla.Name] = (function(x) { return function(){ x.action(); }})(bla);
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mnbayazit/55caP/)

Comment: great, forgot that one ! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The value of `bla` is changing and the function you create will always use the value as it is when it is called.

You might create a closure to protect the `bla` variable :

```
for(var i =0; i< arr.length; i++) {
    (function(bla){
        arr2[bla.Name] = function(){ bla.action() };
    })(arr[i]);
}
```

If your `action` functions don't need any context or arguments, you might also simplify the loop in

```
for(var i =0; i< arr.length; i++) {
    var bla = arr[i];
    arr2[bla.Name] = bla.action;
}
```